# how to save figure correctly? the figure has nothing after i saved

Tags: python, matplotlib

i write this code below and nothing happens, but the file .jpg has added to my directory
Anyone can help me to solve this codes??

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
netflix_raw['country'].sort_values(ascending=True).value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='barh')
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.title("Top 10 Country Film Maker - Netflix", fontsize=18)
plt.text(1400,9, 'Data source: Kaggle')
plt.xlabel('Amount of Film')
plt.show()
plt.savefig('top10countryfilmmaker.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: `plt.show()` needs to be set last.

Answer (score 0):

You should omit `plt.show()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4,5))
netflix_raw['country'].sort_values(ascending=True).value_counts()[:10].plot(kind='barh')
plt.xticks(rotation=60)
plt.title("Top 10 Country Film Maker - Netflix", fontsize=18)
plt.text(1400,9, 'Data source: Kaggle')
plt.xlabel('Amount of Film')
plt.savefig('top10countryfilmmaker.jpg', bbox_inches='tight')
```